# Can we easily check whether a number is in this sequence?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Here :

https://oeis.org/A060650

the positive integers $\ n\ $ are shown for which there is exactly one non-abelian group of order $\ n\ $.

> Is there an easy criterion to check whether a number is in this sequence ?

It seems that a number in this sequence must be cubefree (Is this actually true ?) I am also aware of a formula for the number of groups of order $\ n\ $ when $\ n\ $ is squarefree, although this formula is quite complicated.

If the number is even, it seems that it is in the list if and only if it is twice an odd prime.

Comment: You can prove the cube free condition by saying n=p^3*m. Then using two nonabelian groups of order p^3 times a cyclic group of order m. There are two nonisomorphic groups  of order p^3 by an exercise. See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf

Comment: If $n$ is squarefree, then it is will be in that list if and only there is exactly one pair of prime divisors $(p,q)$ of $n$ such that $p\mid q-1$. There should be a similar statement for cubefree groups, you might be able to infer it from http://users.monash.edu.au/~heikod/hddats/CubeFreeTh.pdf for example (note that we can limit ourselves to groups of odd order, and thus soluble groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be cubefree and call a prime $p$ dividing $n$ "simple" if $p^2$ does not divide $n$, and "double" otherwise. As we run over the pairs of primes dividing $n$, $p$ and $q$, count the following occurences.

A. $p\mid q-1$ and $p$ or $q$ is a double prime.

B. $p\mid q-1$ and both $p$ and $q$ are simple primes.

C. $p\mid q+1$ and $p$ and $q$ are double primes.

D. $p\mid q+1$ and $p$ is a simple prime and $q$ is a double prime.

Then I think $n$ is in your list if and only A and C occur $0$ times, while B and D occur exactly once in combined total.

Here's a sketch of a proof. First, if $4$ divides $n$, then $n$ is not in the list. (If $n=4$, then $G$ is abelian, otherwise we can easily find two non-abelian groups, say dicyclic, and dihedral direct with cyclic.) So we may assume $4$ does not divide $n$ and $n$ is soluble, so all the Hall subgroups exist.

If all the Hall subgroups involving two primes are abelian, then I think $G$ is abelian, so we need some Hall subgroup involving two primes to be nonabelian. This is about groups of order dividing $p^2q^2$ and I think A, B, C and D are the only possibilities.

Now, suppose $p\mid q-1$ and $q$ is a double prime. Then we get two nonabelian groups (say $q\times (q\rtimes p)$ and $(q^2\rtimes p$). If $p$ is a double prime, then we have $p\times (q\rtimes p)$ and $(q\rtimes p^2)$. We can use this to create different nonabelian groups $G$. This shows A cannot occur.

Similarly, if C occurs, we get at least two nonabelian groups, by starting with $(q^2\rtimes p)\times p$ and $q^2\rtimes p^2$, so C cannot occur.

Finally, if B or D occur, we get a nonabelian group, and if we get more than one occurrence, it's not hard to show that there are at least two different nonabelian groups.  (It remains to show that if indeed there is only one occurrence, then we get only one nonabelian group.)

Comment: Thank you. (+1) SInce I have no access currently to GAP (because my windows broke down) , is there an online version that can calculate the number of groups for cubefree orders (we only need those) upto , lets say, $50\ 000$ ? I would be content to know the examples in this range.

Comment: Do you really want the number of groups of cubefree order, or just the orders where there is exactly one? If the latter, why not just program the above?